# Editing php.ini on vagrant box

Tags: php, vagrant, vagrantfile

Does anyone know how to edit the mail setting in the php.ini file by using Vagrant.

so I would ssh in terminal like so:

cd myapp

vagrant ssh

then what>?

Comment: Depends a lot on how PHP is being installed and what OS your box is using. Seeing the vagrantfile and any scripts you use to configure the box after it's initialized would help.

Comment: its quite lengthy so pasted the full vagrantfile here > https://gist.github.com/lstables/10421433

Answer (score 22):

Depending on your box, it might be

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

then adopt you changes and restart with

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: For me, that file is empty.

Comment: Running `php --ini` will show the path of the configuration file.

Comment: `php --ini` looks for php location from your console/device. Executing `phpinfo();` finds the php location that your project is running.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing what specific setting you want and what you want it changed to, you could try adding a shell script to the end of your Vagrantfile (in the "Local Scripts" area) to do a search and replace on the ini file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed -i.bak s/STRING_TO_REPLACE/STRING_TO_REPLACE_IT_WITH/g /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Failing that, you can use [ini_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) in your project (preferably in a bootstrap) to change mail settings on a per-project basis.

Comment: Ok maybe i'll just use ini_set then nothing major just windered how to do with Vagrant

Comment: Have a look at Puppet - it's a little more complicated but you can make that kind of configuration change right in the Puppetfile without having to mess with shell scripts or remembering to set something in code later. A really good resource starting out is PuPHPet - https://puphpet.com/.

Comment: Yeah tried that but got a little confused.com over it!

Answer (score 2):

In my case where I'm using scotchbox on vagrant, changing the `php.ini` file won't reflect changes in `phpinfo()` function output so I changed `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/user.ini` file which could be a bare file or a file with few lines declaring php error display, I add my configurations here e.g. `upload_max_filesize = 64M`Save the change and issue `sudo service apache2 restart`. Viewed the phpinfo page and I can see the updated filesize.